Localize page title in Vaadin
How can I localize page titles in Vaadin?
I tried the following annotation but it didn't work:
@Route(URL)
@PageTitle("${user.account}")
@RolesAllowed({"ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE"})
public class AccountEditorView extends VerticalLayout {

The page title was not resolved but literally "${user.account}" instead of its value from the i18n message source.
Is there an annotation based way or do I have to implement HasDynamicTitle?

There is none in the core up to at least the current 24.3. You have to roll your own via HasDynamicTitle

The @PageTitle is indeed more static in nature. For localisation it's best to implement the HasDynamicTitle interface. Do note that you can use only one of them in a class, not both.
The Vaadin 24 documentation example of using HasDynamicTitle can be found here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/page-titles#setting-the-page-title-dynamically
